# Angular JS: Use orderby with a select tag selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to order a table of order details.
The property to order by is selected from a dropdown list in a select tag.

The two properties are order id and product count, which I get from a controller function.

The function:

```
$scope.countProducts =  function(order){
    var counter = 0;

    order.products.forEach(function(currProd){
    counter += currProd.count;
    });
    return counter;
};
```

The Id is a numeric variable.

My view :
The details table :

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!-- a headline row -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="order in orders | orderby: orderByAttr">
      <!-- order details rows -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The select tag with the options:

```
<select ng-model="orderByAttr">
  <option ng-value="order.id">id</option>
  <option ng-value="countProducts(order)"> products     count </option>
</select>
```

How can I pass the value of the option to the order by filter? 
And how do I bind the countProduct result to the select value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your HTML to this:

```
    <div>
    <select ng-model="orderByAttr">
        <option ng-value="'id">id</option>
        <option ng-value="'productCount'">Product Count</option>

    </select>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="order in orders | orderBy: orderByAttr">
    <div>
        <div>{{order.id}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what your data looks like but I would think it is something similar to this:

```
$scope.orders = [{
    id: 1,
    products : [{
      productId: 1,
      name: 'Okra'

    },
  {productId: 3,
  name: 'Pear'}]

}, 
{
id: 2,
products : [{
  productId: 2,
  name: 'Apple'
}]
},
{
  id:3,
  products: [{
    productId: 1,
    name: 'Okra'
  }
  ]
}
]
```

You can use a 'forEach' to get your product count like this:  `enter code here`

```
    angular.forEach($scope.orders, function(value,key){
  $scope.orders[key].productCount = value.products.length;
})
```

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6DIGzHfG1X4xEUCD5Rtk?p=preview).  Let me know if this is not what you need.

Comment: I have worked with that foreach concept and it worked but I still can't dynamiclly change the property to order by. My select looks excactly like in your example and I can get it to order it only by the prodCount property. For some reason it only chooses the prodCount option.

Comment: Check your data.  The Id field has to be spelled EXACTLY as the Id field in your data. 'id' won't work if your data field is called 'Id' or 'ID'.

Answer (score 0):

Ther's a problem with your approach: `orderByAttr` should take a value of an attribute name like `id` for order id and `name` if it was an existing attribute for your items. Since the count is a generated attribute I recommend you to use a function for ordering:

```
$scope.customOrder = function (order) {
  if (orderByAttr === 'id') {
    return order.id;
  } else {
    return $scope.countProducts(order);
  }
};
```

And your selection should look like:

```
<select ng-model="orderByAttr">
  <option ng-value="'id'">id</option>
  <option ng-value="'count'">products count</option>
</select>
```